# Type Mismatch using win32com in Python

Tags: python, win32com

I am trying to use Python to run an external program using its COM interface.  In general, everything works as expected.  The only problem I’m having is that any time I try to retrieve a value from the program using their GetValue method, I get the following error (code included).

This method is supposed to overwrite the value of my Value variable.  The function takes 3 arguments, and I have verified that the error is related to the first argument (Value) by using separate functions successfully that only take the last 2 arguments.  The documentation for the COM interface mentions this issue for C#, and their recommended solution was to define Value as an Object type variable and set the value to null.  I have it set to None below, but I’ve also tried setting it to different int/float/string with no success.

I receive this error whether or not I use the EnsureModule command before dispatch.

See the code below

```
  Object = win32.Dispatch(“COMObject”)
     

    Object.OpenFile(“Filename”)
    Value = None
    Object.GetValue(Value,0,1)


    Exception has occurred:com_error
    (-2147352571,’type mismatch’,None,1)
```

Comment: What does the Type Library say? If you have the Windows SDK (an install option with Visual Studio), you can find a utility called `oleview.exe`. The first time you run it, start the program as Administrator. You can then find your COM object and see its interface. This will at least tell you what type the first parameter of `GetValue` should be. It might be that it is expecting it as a Variant type, in which case this link might help: http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/html/com/win32com/HTML/variant.html

Comment: You just solved my problem - thank you so much!!!  That document described everything perfectly, and using their method worked on the first try.  I REALLY appreciate it i I probably would have given up otherwise.